# Is boost::variant rocket science? (And should I therefore avoid it for simple problems?)

Tags: c++, boost

OK, so I have this tiny little corner of my code where I'd like my function return either of (`int`, `double`, `CString`) to clean up the code a bit.

So I think: No problem to write a little union-like wrapper `struct` with three members etc. *But wait!* Haven't I read of `boost::variant`? Wouldn't this be exactly what I need? This would save me from messing around with a wrapper struct myself! (Note that I already have the boost library available in my project.)

So I fire up my browser, navigate to [Chapter 28. Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/variant.html) and lo and behold:

> The variant class template is a safe, generic, stack-based discriminated union container, offering a simple solution for manipulating an object from a heterogeneous set of types [...]

Great! Exactly what I need!

But then it goes on:

> **Boost.Variant vs. Boost.Any**
>
> - Boost.Any makes little use of template metaprogramming techniques (avoiding potentially hard-to-read error messages and significant compile-time processor and memory demands).
>
> [...]
>
> **Troubleshooting**
>
> "Internal heap limit reached" -- Microsoft Visual C++ -- The compiler option /ZmNNN can increase the memory allocation limit. The NNN is a scaling percentage (i.e., 100 denotes the default limit). (Try /Zm200.)
>
> [...]

*Uh oh.* So using boost::variant may significantly increase compile-time and generate hard-to-read error messages. What if someone moves my use of boost::variant to a common header, will our project suddenly take lots longer to compile? **Am I introducing an (unnecessarily) complex type?**

*Should I use `boost::variant` for my **simple tiny** problem?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boost.variant is not that complex, IMHO. Yes, it is template based, but it doesn't use any really complex feature of C++. I've used quite a bit and no problem at all. I think in your case it would help better describing what your code is doing.

Another way of thinking is transforming what that function returns into a more semantically rich structure/class that allows interpreting which inner element is interesting, but that depends on your design.

Answer (score 7):

Generally, use `boost::variant` if you *do* want a discriminated union (`any` is for unknown types -- think of it as some kind of equivalent to how `void*` is used in C).

Some advantages include exception handling, potential usage of less space than the sum of the type sizes, type discriminated "visiting". Basically, stuff you'd want to perform on the discriminated union.

However, for `boost::variant` to be efficient, at least one of the types used must be "easily" constructed (read the documentation for more details on what "easily" means).

Comment: Somehow this answer seems to miss the question. I think I asked if boost variant is overkill due to its implementation/advanced features. Its *intended* use seems clear enough.

Comment: How does one judge overkill? The question doesn't specify how the discriminated union is going to be used (sure, it is for a multi-type return value, but how is the return value used?) Even the question about whether the compilation times will be much longer is ill-posed, as it is a relative question (answer depends on current project size) and there is no information on the base value.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of boost element comes from functional programming, where you have [variants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) around every corner.

It should be a way to have a type-safe approach to returning a kind of value that can be of many precise types. This means that is useful to solve your problem BUT you should consider if it's really what you need to do.

The added value compared to other approaches that tries to solve the same problem should be the type-safety (you won't be able to place whatever you want inside a variant without noticing, in opposition to a `void*`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't use it because, to me, it's a symptom of bad design.

Either  your method should return an object that implements a determinated interface or it should be split in more than one method. Design should be reviewed, anyway.

Comment: Variants are not bad design, there are situations where they are very much called for. Sometimes what you perform a completely different action depending on what type you get.

Comment: That was only my opinion: to me, there's almost always a way to improve the code design if you have to resort to variants.

Comment: In C++, hiding the difference behind an interface isn't such a big improvement. Then you have to resort to passing (dynamically allocated) pointers around, and you lose runtime efficiency. And if the problem calls for *just returning one of these three types*, then I don't see how it's a problem. Say it's a function to parse input from the user. It either contains an int, a double or some other string. A variant type sounds like *exactly* what I'd want.

Comment: You lose runtime efficiency that probably you'll lose anyway later when you will have to ascertain the *variant* real type with *if* or *switch*. What I'd want in such a case depends on what I have to do with that input, maybe always returning a string would be ok.

Comment: At the point where you're dealing with user input, runtime efficiency really does not depend on something like variant. Any processor made this century can keep up with human input. Furthermore, the most expensive part of input is the format validation, not the variant in which you stuff the result.

Comment: @Simone: boost::variant also has the visitor concept, where you can use template specializations to take special actions for every type. Afaik, the variant implementation resolves those at compile time. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.advanced

Comment: To me, avoiding some features or idioms _without replacement_ intentionally _is_ bad design. Note that OOD is _not_ the design. Things called "interface" are actually far more general than a poor set of OO features (or features combination) provided by the particular "OO" language, which is often based on a unfortunate and disabled type system, and usually limited by the ABI and other implementation details which are against the original true purpose of the designer of interface who clearly knows what he really want.